# Background Service In Android 8 or above

Tags: android

Want to send Latitude and longitude on some interval when app is in background or killed. Alarm manager and broadcast receiver not working in Android 8 or above. If anyone have proper solution.pls help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **WorkManager**

[image]

[Introducing WorkManager](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712)

[Getting started with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)